# handleWatchKitExtensionRequest limitations

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

Are there restrictions on what you can do in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`? I tried returning a `UIImage` from the resource bundle but I get a `nil` reply.

This works:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    reply(@{@"Returning the number 1":@(1)});
}
```

This fails:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-152x152.png"];
    reply(@{@"image":image});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary you pass around must be property list compliant, meaning that you need to convert classes that aren't strings, numbers, dicts, and arrays, into NSData before you send it. [How to convert UIImage to NSData.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623931/get-underlying-nsdata-from-uiimage)