# How to save CGImage to Data in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdata, cgimage, cfdata

This code type checks and compiles but then crashes. How do I save a `CGImage` to `Data` so that I can read it in again later.

```
let cgi: CGImage? = ...        
var mData = Data()
let imageDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mData as! CFMutableData, 
                                                 kUTTypePNG, 1, nil)!
CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDest, cgi!, nil)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDest)
```

The last line crashes. Error in console is:

```
2018-01-17 19:25:43.656664-0500 HelloPencil[2799:3101092] -[_NSZeroData 
  appendBytes:length:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c80029c0
2018-01-17 19:25:43.658420-0500 HelloPencil[2799:3101092] *** Terminating app 
  due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
  '-[_NSZeroData appendBytes:length:]: unrecognized selector 
  sent to instance 0x1c80029c0'
```

That cast from `Data` to `CFMutableData` was recommended by Xcode, but maybe it's wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is the way you are creating your mutable data. `Data` cannot be directly converted to `NSMutableData`.

The only way to cast from `Data` to `CFMutableData` is casting it first to `NSData`, get its mutableCopy `NSMutableData` and cast it to `CFMutableData`.

> `NSMutableData` is toll-free bridged to `CFMutableData`

But in this case it doesn't make any sense considering that you have no data to be converted. Just use `CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0)` to initialize a new `CFMutableData` object:

```
if let cgi = cgi, 
    let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0),
    let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, "public.png" as CFString, 1, nil) {
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgi, nil)
    if CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) {
        let data = mutableData as Data
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            print(image.size)
        }
    } else {
        print("Error writing Image")
    }
}
```

edit/update: **Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension CGImage {
    var png: Data? {
        guard let mutableData = CFDataCreateMutable(nil, 0),
            let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(mutableData, "public.png" as CFString, 1, nil) else { return nil }
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, self, nil)
        guard CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) else { return nil }
        return mutableData as Data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. I may report a bug about the cast. If a cast from A to B succeeds, I don't think it should die later because A wasn't really a B.